# Visiting site using Chrome restarts device

Tags: chrome-for-android, reboot

I came across an unusual behaviour in Chrome (50.0.2661.89), running on a Galaxy S7 (SM-G930F)/Android 6.0.1 . The behaviour seems to be repeatable, causing my device to restart every time I scroll through a particular page.

- Start from a standard boot, no other apps run since startup.
- Open Chrome.
- Navigate to
  http://www.fieryflavors.com/spicy-food-hiccups/
- Swipe down the page
  (haven't managed to pin down a specific point of trouble yet).
- Device
  restarts.

The page in question doesn't *seem* to have anything tremendously nefarious happening in its source code (still poking it a bit, will update if anything turns up). I haven't come across this particular issue with Chrome on Android in the past.

Is this common? Is there a particular HTML/CSS/javascript/etc. string that's known to cause device restarts?

**UPDATE**

I'm not sure that it's an 'official' Chromium bug yet, but it certainly looks like I'm not alone:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=614422#c28

The problem appears to be specific to the Galaxy S7 and S7 Edge and is likely triggered by video embedded within adverts (the issue is intermittent, disappearing when new ads rotate into each problematic page). As such it's perhaps less likely that the issue lies within Android, and more that it's a Samsung problem or a very specific incompatibility between Android/Chrome/Samsung hardware.

Comment: Have you seen this same issue on any other devices? I expect it's something wrong with your device rather than the site itself (although it could be triggering some issue on your device causing it to restart). It does not restart my Nexus 6P. Does your device restart when doing anything else?

Comment: The issue doesn't appear on a Sony Xperia X I've tested either. No other applications on the S7 cause a reboot. No other sites I've visited in Chrome on that phone cause reboots. Could very well be specific to my particular device, but it would be useful to confirm that before I start checking random things.

Comment: It doesn't reboot for me. (Nexus 6P running Android N). Can you check if there are any updates for the Google Chrome app?

Comment: Everything's up to date.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have antivirus installed on your phone? If so go to settings and lower the security setting from high to medium i sems as though its a security feature you may have on i just visted the page from crome on 2 different. Devices and had no problems or bo restart. I did however visit the page from my home pc that does have firewall antivirus set to high and i got Warning not secure page.
Hope this helps.

Comment: There's no third party antivirus software running on the device.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it cause unusal restarts in one of Lenovo K8+ (marino) device.
Initially that user faced this issue in oreo then he reverted back to nougat.

> With stock chrome installed there is no issue but if he updates it to
>   latest through play store and surf any website for a while, the device power off for few minutes
>   and then automatically boots the system (power on itself).

**Maybe**

- A driver bug
- JS engine issue

Let me catch some logs and if possible i will write a patch to fix this issue.I will update this answer as soon as there is some positive progress.

Edit:

I have filed an bug report to lenovo forum and it can be found [here](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/K8-XT1902-Smartphones/BUG-K8-Plus-Random-Power-Off/td-p/4249773)